# Посоветуйте подход к обработке ошибок связанных с переданными на сервер данными с иcпользованием XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Я работаю над сайтом. В работе использую Laravel и Vue.

Посоветуйте подход к обработке ошибок возникающих на сервере в результате валидации входящих параметров адресной строки либо переменных переданных как JSON объект? Меня интересует практичный подход к тому как именно донести пользователю текстовую информацию о причинах ошибки.

Сразу скажу что я понимаю что наверное, на этот вопрос трудно дать один ответ. Поэтому я больше рассчитываю на то что просто увижу практичные советы. Либо услышу рекомендации по прочтению статей из серии "лучшие практики".

Уточняя вопрос. Приведу ряд подвопросов.

- Например, как показать пользователю что он передал с помощью GET запроса в адресной строке неправильные данные? Отослать ему json с текстом? Или переданную в качестве ответа на запрос в браузер ошибку удобнее и правильнее было бы обработать в самом браузере перехватив ошибку на сам запрос и как результат дать текстовое пояснение?
- Нужно ли вообще что то отсылать пользователю на возникшую ошибку в результате валидации переменных переданных на сервер в json объект вместе с POST запросом.  Под обработкой я понимаю, именно текстовый ответ на ошибку отсылаемый в браузер, а не то, что валидация входящих данных вообще не нужна. Или же вместо текстового ответа с сервера правильнее было бы осуществлять валидацию в браузере при заполнении формы, ну а ошибки связанные с обработкой входящих данных на сервер просто никак для пользователя не доводить.

В общем, подытоживая, хотелось бы понять как более практично подойти к в опросу обработки ошибок входящих на сервер параметов в виде параметров адресной строки либо json объекта.

Расскажите как это делаете вы. И делаете ли вообще.

Answer (score 0):

Имхо лучшим путем будет отправка ответа с [нужным кодом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP) и текстовым описанием в качестве тела ответа. Большинство возможных ошибок уже описаны этими кодами состояния, в секциях 4хх и 5хх.
По второму пункту ответ очевиден - запрос подразумевает ответ. Если ответа нет - значит с сервером случилось что-то страшное (его украли/он сгорел/уборщица опять выдернула кабель)

P.S. - ошибки валидации - это безусловно [400 Bad request](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#400)

Comment: По поводу POST(2й пункт) и ответа. То у меня сложилось следующее впечатление. Если в браузере перед отправкой формы, происходит валидация при помощи js то он выдаст все сообщения о неправильном заполнении. В случае если  какой то любопытствующий просто решит отправить запрос с страницы, отключив валидацию, то зачем ему вообще видеть какой либо ответ. Хотя с другой стороны. Зачем валидировать на стороне браузера при помощи js если можно воспользоватся просто готовым функционалом Laravel и отправить JSON с комментариями к ошибке. Голова кругом что то идет.

Comment: Поскольку ваш вопрос довольно общий, я дал общий ответ, который сгодится и в том случае, если из вашего вопроса убрать слова Vue, PHP, Laravel, Ajax. В некоторых случаях действительно удобнее пользоватся JSON определенного формата (например если вы используете какой нибудь другой протокол, или ваш сервер стоит за прокси, который не вполне адекватно реагирует на коды ответа, отличающиеся от 200)

Comment: Никаких перечисленных вами особых случаев пока нет, просто пытаюсь осмыслить хотя бы на уровне базового понимания вот и уточняю.